# Error during compilation when using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, g++, pybind11

I'm trying to compile a basic example copied and pasted directly from `pybind11`, with `g++-8` on a Mac.

This is the c++ code (`example.cpp`):

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

When I use the following command, it works:

```
/usr/local/bin/g++-8 -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` example.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

However, when I add in `-mcmodel=large`, such as the following

```
/usr/local/bin/g++-8 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -mcmodel=large -fPIC -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` example.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

It would give me a bunch of errors that look like:

> /var/folders/zk/zxm107qd503bgh5qxvdhv6cr0000gv/T//ccbv0Hje.s:75886:19:
>   error: invalid variant 'PLTOFF'
>           movabsq $__ZdlPv@PLTOFF, %rax

I have Googled this error but I couldn't find a helpful thread. Also, I want to use `g++` (not Xcode) since it's lightweight and popular in my community. I've tried different versions of `g++` (6, 7, and 8) but I see the same error.

I need to use `mcmodel=large` because the actual code that I deal with could require large memory allocations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you need `-mcmodel=large`? The large code model is only needed if the size of your *code and static data* exceeds 2 GiB.  Heap allocations do not count.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I might and want to prepare for the worst.

Comment: I doubt `-mcmodel=large` is supported on Darwin, so you'd have to use a different operating system to be prepared.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer where can I find some documentation on this?

Comment: Your best chance a GCC bug reports such as [this one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69061). I don't think Apple maintains documentation for the legacy toolchain anymore (at least not on the web).

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Thank you. Can you use a different kernel from Darwin?